# Decorator design pattern using inheritance vs interfaces

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I'd like to implement the Decorator design pattern using inheritance (`Decorator extends Component`) because i need access to the protected fields/methods of the Component class.

The problem is that the Component class represents an algorithm, it performs some preprocessing upon construction and holds a significant amount of data. Now each time I'll be decorating a Component I'll create a new Decorator instance which will require the construction of a new (useless) Component instance performing unneeded computations and holding unneeded data.

I wanted to use interfaces instead of inheritance but then I wont be able to access Component's protected information.

Am i right to worry about the waste of resources when extending the Component class? And if so, how can i avoid it without losing access to the information i need?

One final note: I could create the Decorator instance supplying it with "dummy" data so that it will perform minimal amount of computation but this solution feels messy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would count as the decorator pattern at all actually. Sounds more like plain old inheritance.

> ***Am i right to worry about the waste of resources when extending the Component class?***

Obviously depends on how much resources you're wasting.

> ***And if so, how can i avoid it without losing access to the information i need?***

You could perhaps "open up" `Component` by extending it and adding methods for accessing the protected parts you need. Then use interfaces and composition to implement a decorator for the this new class.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, your `Component` class is not designed "to be decorated". Have you thought of refactoring it?